# Using MemberQ on a list of matrices

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, adjacency-matrix

I have a function whose output is a list of adjacency matrices of bipartite graphs and I want to check if a randomly generated matrix has one of these matrices as a sub-matrix within it.

My function for generating the list of matrices is:

```
Krsvariants[r_, s_] := Module[{aa}, aa = Subsets[Range[1, r + s], {r}];
  Table[
   Table[
    If[MemberQ[Tuples[aa[[k]], 2], {i, j}] \[Or] 
      MemberQ[Tuples[Complement[Range[1, r + s], aa[[k]]], 2], {i,j}], 0, 1], {i, 1, r + s}, {j, 1, r + s}], 
{k, 1, Length[aa]}]]
```

And for r = 2, s = 3 has output

```
{{{0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 
   0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 
   1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 
   0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 
   1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0,
    1, 1, 1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 
   1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 
   0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 
   0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0,
    1, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1,
    1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 
   1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 
   1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1,
    0, 0}}}
```

Which corresponds to 10 different matrices. I then wish to check if a random matrix contains at least one of these 10 and count how many.

```
TK23[M_, n_] := Module[{S, k, i},
  S = Subsets[Range[n], {5}];
  Return[Count[
    Table[MemberQ[Krsvariants[2, 3], M[[S[[k]], S[[k]]]]] , {k, 1, 
      Binomial[n, 5]}], True]];]
```

But when I run this it always seems to return zero even when applied to matrices which definitely should contain one of the 10.

Comment: I'm puzzled by your problem description.  Why can't you just use `Count`? E.g., `mmK=Krsvariants[2,3];Count[mmK,mmK[[1]]]`.

Comment: I want to consider all the elements of Krsvariants and not just the indiviual elements within it as for this case I want to count the number of times any of the elements of Krsvariants appear in for example a 10x10 matrix

Comment: By "appear in", did you mean "is a submatrix of"?  Or do you really mean (as it appears) can be produced by striking out any 5 rows and the same 5 columns of the 10 x 10 matrix?  The answer below assumes the latter.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I want is if you take a 10x10 matrix for example, it checks every possible 5x5 submatrix in this case of the 10x10 and checks if it matches any of the Krsvariants and then counts the total number of matches.

Comment: In your initial code, you took the *same* set of rows and of columns (e.g., the first five rows *and* the first five columns).  That's what I did below.  Are you now saying you want them to vary independently? Added.

Answer (score 1):

```
mmK = Krsvariants[2, 3]
tk23[mM_] := Module[{mS, n},
  n = Length@mM;
  mS = Subsets[Range[n], {5}];
  Total@Table[Count[mmK, mM[[s, s]]], {s, mS}]
  ]
```

**Edit:** If you want to vary row indexes separately from column indexes, use

```
Total@Table[Count[mmK, mM[[s1, s2]]], {s1, mS}, {s2, mS}]
```

Comment: Upon further thinking, the first expression you have would be what I want but when I run it `tk23[AdjacencyMatrix[G[10, 0.6]]]` on a random graph I have generated of 10 points and edge probability 0.6 I always get zero, which for those parameters shouldn't be the case, I have calculated the expected number of bipartite graphs of size 2,3 should be about 3

Comment: The code does what you requested.  It is easily tested.  `mA = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}];
s = Sort@RandomSample[Range@10, 5];
mA[[s, s]] = mmK[[1]];
tk23[mA]`